# Google custom panorama (streetview) limit min zoom

Tags: zooming, google-street-view, panoramas

I have custom Google panorama. I init it like this:

```
panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('map'), {
    pano: 'pano',
    visible: true,
    panoProvider: get_custom_panorama,
    pov: {
        heading: 345,
        pitch: -10,
        zoom: 0.7
    },
    mode : 'webgl',
    zoomControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM,
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE
    },
    addressControl: false
});
```

**I want to limit minimum zoom level to, let's say, 1.**

Is it possible? I don't see any helpful options or listeners I can use.

The closest what I've found is:

```
panorama.addListener('zoom_changed', function() {
    if (panorama.getZoom()<1)
    {
        var pov=panorama.getPov();

        panorama.setPov({
            heading: pov.heading,
            pitch: pov.pitch,
            zoom: 1
        });
    }
});
```

But even this doesn't work. And you can see why: on zoom_changed event zoom is already changed. I need something like "before_zoom_changed" listener...